# Grab variable value from part of CSS class name?

Tags: jquery, css, variables, append

I have multiple classes, listed:

.sub1

.sub2

.sub3

etc.
What I am trying to do is have a variable "x" that grabs its value from the numerical value at the end of my CSS classes.
What I have tried is:

```
 var subList = $('.sub'+x)
 function(x) {
   // my function code
 }
```

I'm still relatively new to jQuery, so I don't even know if this is remotely correct. Help?

Comment: Are you trying to do something different with each of the subs? Do you know a priori how many of them you'll have, or not? If so, you could do some sort of loop.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure it will just be the three. I'm sure I can do a loop, I'm just looking for the proper way to append my variable "x" value to the end of the CSS class name, be it a loop, or some method similar to the code example I gave, or some other method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6do5fm44/) that will show you how to do what you want with class or id.

One thing to remember is that javascript/jQuery LOVES strings, and most of the "parts" of javascript can be treated like a string. So you can "embed" all kinds of information into an element's attributes and then extract it later.

There is an atypical attribute selector that can be helpful - example: [class^=val]

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

JS

```
var class1 = $( 'div' ).attr('class');
var firstthree =  class1.slice(3);
$('div').css('width', firstthree);

var id1 = $( 'div' ).attr('id');                              
var firstid = id1.slice(5);
$('div').css('height', firstid);
```